# Port WordPress sanitize_title to Delphi

Tags: wordpress, delphi

In WordPress, when I input a title for a post and save it, then a slug will automatically generated based on the title. After searching online, I find it is implemented via sanitize_title, so I try to port it to Delphi.

But after checking its source code:

```php
function sanitize_title( $title, $fallback_title = '', $context = 'save' ) {
    $raw_title = $title;

    if ( 'save' === $context ) {
        $title = remove_accents( $title );
    }

    /**
     * Filters a sanitized title string.
     *
     * @since 1.2.0
     *
     * @param string $title     Sanitized title.
     * @param string $raw_title The title prior to sanitization.
     * @param string $context   The context for which the title is being sanitized.
     */
    $title = apply_filters( 'sanitize_title', $title, $raw_title, $context );

    if ( '' === $title || false === $title ) {
        $title = $fallback_title;
    }

    return $title;
}
```

I cannot find any codes that perform the replacement of whitespace to '-'.

1. remove_accents only remove accents, not related to whitespace.
2. apply_filters is apply a filter, if there is no filter, then nothing happens.

Other than these two ,there are no codes make the transform. Why?

Comment: Elsewhere there will be one or more `add_filter` calls adding filters to `'sanitize_title'` which is then called by the `apply_filter`. in your example.

Comment: How can I find the add_filter calls?

Comment: By using a [text editor which can search in files](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#find-in-files-tab) you search **every** file for `apply_filter` and then see all the matches. Also please put more care into your Q formatting and its tags (so it isn't highlighted as per _Pascal_).

Comment: You are probably looking for [`sanitize_title_with_dashes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title_with_dashes/). The fourth to last code line is where spaces are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the WordPress core, WordPress uses the sanitize_title hook to apply its own filter (you can find that in this code):
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-filters.php

The function it call is sanitize_title_with_dashes:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title_with_dashes/

That's the function you are looking for.